# Disable / re-enable LUIS recognizer prior to entering waterfall dialog

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am in the same situation as many, where I am triggering a choicePrompt then LUIS is bringing me out of my WaterfallDialog and is trying to match the selected choice with one of my intents. I have seen many posts about this same issue, and many of the solutions involve using `LuisRecognizer.onEnabled()` to disable calls to LUIS while inside a dialogStack. However, this must have been changed in the v4 SDK because this method no longer exists inside the LuisRecognizer class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.luis.luisrecognizer?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). I saw a solution involving state not being used, however in `Startup.cs` I have a `MemoryStorage` and I pass it to what I believe to be the correct places:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddBot<BasicBot>(options =>
        {
            ...
            IStorage dataStore = new MemoryStorage();
            var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);
            options.State.Add(conversationState);
            var userState = new UserState(dataStore);
            options.State.Add(userState);
            services.AddSingleton(sp => new BotServices(botConfig));
            services.AddSingleton<BotAccessors>(sp =>
            {
            var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BotFrameworkOptions>>().Value;
            var accessors = new BotAccessors(conversationState, userState)
            {
                CommandState = userState.CreateProperty<string>(BotAccessors.CommandStateName),
                ConversationDialogState = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(BotAccessors.DialogStateName),
            };
            return accessors;
        });
        services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {
            var section = this.Configuration.GetSection("Luis");
            var luisApp = new LuisApplication(
                applicationId: "2d...",
                endpointKey: "64...",
                endpoint: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/")

            var luisPredictionOptions = new LuisPredictionOptions
            {
                IncludeAllIntents = true,
            };
            return new LuisRecognizer(
                application: luisApp,
                predictionOptions: luisPredictionOptions,
                includeApiResults: true);
        });
    }
```

With this configuration, I still get Luis interrupting when I just want to move onto the next step of a waterfall dialog after a Prompt. Does anyone have any insights?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code sample is quite exhaustive. For the sake of brevity and readability could you try to [edit] your question and remove parts that are not necessary to be included? Perhaps some Exception-s?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've removed parts that are not necessary.